Troubles with InputFile component in Blazor (Server Side) .NET 6
I created simple Blazor component for pictures preview and upload.
InputFile component is hidden and label is used as button to open choose file dialog.
After file/image choosing I want to show the image on preview.
I read the file end encode it to base64.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div class="m-2">        
    <InputFile style="display: none" id="productPictureInput" OnChange="HandleImageUpload" accept="image/*" />
    <label for="productPictureInput" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;" @onclick="TriggerFileInput">Add Image</label>
    @if (imagePreviewSrc != null)
    {
        <img src="@imagePreviewSrc" alt="Image preview" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; margin-left: 10px;" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string? imagePreviewSrc;

    private async void TriggerFileInput()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync( "triggerClickEvent", "productPictureInput" );
    }

    private async void HandleImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var imageFile = e.GetMultipleFiles().FirstOrDefault();
        if (imageFile != null)
        {
            var imageStream = imageFile.OpenReadStream();
            var buffer = new byte[imageStream.Length];
            await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer);
            imagePreviewSrc = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}

When I try the component on other Blazor page I get strange behavior.
Load (choose file) dialog opens twice, image is only partly loaded (see attached image) and then I cannot change (choose other) image.

So please tip me what's is going wrong?
Thanks.
JS function:
function triggerClickEvent(elementId) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).click();
}

It might be important to mention - it's ASP.NET MVC application, .NET 6. I added services.AddServerSideBlazor(); to Startup.cs.

Hello, first of all I propose that you use this library for input file from Microsoft https://fluentui-blazor.net/InputFile its quite good, there is no need for reinventing a wheel. Second writting file as a base64 and put set it to path can be buggy. What is a resolution of the image ? There is a limit of how large image passed that way can be.

Does this InputFile component you are using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0

You didn't provide a method for triggerClickEvent but I'm afraid that is used for triggering the file upload dialog. And this might be the issue, as I test with <Inputfile /> which worked well.

Yes, I use InputFile component you specified.

To avoid opening choose file dialog twice we just need to add preventDefault:
    <label for="productPictureInput" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;"
           @onclick="TriggerFileInput" @onclick:preventDefault="true">Add Image</label>


I used code below which worked well.
@page "/Input"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Inputfile Preview</h3>
<div class="m-2">        
    <InputFile OnChange="@HandleImageUpload" multiple accept="image/*" />
    @if (imagePreviewSrc != null)
    {
        <img src="@imagePreviewSrc" alt="Image preview" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; margin-left: 10px;" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string? imagePreviewSrc;

    private async void HandleImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var imageFile = e.GetMultipleFiles().FirstOrDefault();
        if (imageFile != null)
        {
            var imageStream = imageFile.OpenReadStream();
            var buffer = new byte[imageStream.Length];
            await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer);
            imagePreviewSrc = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}


Then I used this component in another component it worked well too.


I'm afraid Load (choose file) dialog opens twice,and then I cannot change  is due to the js code which you didn't share, could you please share the js code and how you used this component in another component? And image is only partly loaded (see attached image) might be related to css

Why would you enable multiple upload, and then take the first file only?

Copied code snippet from official document and forgot to delete the multipe attribute. My bad, and the take the first file only -- codes from OP's code snippet.

I created new Blazor Web App (Server Side, .NET 8) and added the code but got same result:
@page "/input"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Inputfile Preview</h3>
<div class="m-2">
    <InputFile OnChange="@HandleImageUpload" multiple accept="image/*" />
    @if(imagePreviewSrc != null)
    {
        <img src="@imagePreviewSrc" alt="Image preview" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; margin-left: 10px;" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string? imagePreviewSrc;

    private async void HandleImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var imageFile = e.GetMultipleFiles().FirstOrDefault();
        if(imageFile != null)
        {
            var imageStream = imageFile.OpenReadStream();
            var buffer = new byte[imageStream.Length];
            await imageStream.ReadAsync(buffer);
            imagePreviewSrc = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}


I tried Google Chrome and Opera. One image was loaded and shown correctly. Others not.
When I looked at element (image) code in the browser I saw that base64 code has 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' starting from 15% and to the end.

I tried Google Chrome and Opera. One image was loaded and shown correctly. Others not. --> This means one of the browser worked well? Or one image is good ,2 images are not?

This means one image is good, 2 images are not.

When I looked at element (image) code in the browser I saw that base64 code has 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' from about to 15% and to the end.
In this article ASP.NET Core Blazor file uploads said that SignalR has max message size limit 32 Kb and this is why files are cropped.
I tried to increase the size in Program.cs but it didn't helped.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddHubOptions( options => options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10);


Hi, I found this section which might be a way recommended by Microsoft for uploading images and preview. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#upload-image-preview

This example works for me.
